# What's the purpose of castclass opcode in CLR?

Tags: c#, clr

I came across the `castclass` opcode, which is defined at `Standard ECMA - 335, III.4.3`. I wrote several examples of usage `callvirt` opcode with casting and without. It turns out, that `castclass` opcode has big impact on performance.

For testing, I used following "rough" (in terms of inexact timing of methods' execution) program (compiled in `Release mode` by `msvc 2015`):

```
public class Program
{
    public interface IShow {  string show(); }
    public class ObjectWithShow : IShow 
    { 
        public string show() => "Hello, that's the show method."; 
    }
    // Such functions remains unchanged
    public static string showWithCast(object o) => ((IShow)o).show();
    public static string show(IShow o) => o.show();
    // Such function will be patched later
    public static string showWithoutCast(object o) => ((IShow)o).show();

    public static void Main()
    {
        int N = 10000000;
        var show_object = new ObjectWithShow();
        {

           var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                showWithCast(show_object);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"With cast {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
        {

            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                showWithoutCast(show_object);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Without cast {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
        {

            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                show(show_object);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Without cast {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `IL` codes of `show/showWitCast` functions:

```
.method public hidebysig static string show (class IShow o) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: callvirt instance string IShow::show()
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method Program::show


.method public hidebysig static string showWithCast (object o) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 8
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: castclass IShow
    IL_0006: callvirt instance string IShow::show()
    IL_000b: ret
} // end of method Program::showWithCast
```

Here is code for `showWithoutCast` (NOTE: I patched it by removing `castclass IShow` in `IL` editor. Original version was the same as `showWithCast`)

```
.method public hidebysig static string showWithoutCast (object o) cil managed 
{

    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: callvirt instance string IShow::show()
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method Program::showWithoutCast
```

Results of execution (i7-3370 CPU@3.40GHz, 8GB RAM) show following result:

> With cast 46
>
> Without cast 24
>
> Without cast 23

It turns out that `callvirt` on object without `castclass` shows almost the same result as we used interface instance instead. So, what's the purpose of `castclass`? I guess that `c# compiler` emits such code to ensure, that `callvirt` opcode will not be used on incorrent types (because it cannot perform such checks in compile time). So, following question - Is it consistent `CIL` code, where I intentionally remove usage of `castclass` in places, where I GUARANTEE that method will be used only types which implements `IShow`?

P.S. Of course, You can ask, maybe `show` method should be used then?  But there is cases, where such function cannot be used. If to be brief, I dynamically generate code and  I want to implement generic container (it inherits `IShow`), but its generic parameter can optionally implement interface `IShow`. If generic parameter does not implement interface (for example it is `int`) then I guarantee that the method `show` of container will not be used.

Comment: `Is it consistent CIL code, where I intentionally remove usage of castclass` - What does `peverify` say about the resulting method/assembly?

Comment: @thehennyy, I did not verify code. I just recently learned about `peverify` util. (I'll try to check it out) But good answer is given

Comment: Your question is basically "I removed all the safety systems from my toaster and it still makes toast, so why do we need all that safety stuff?"  To keep you safe! "But suppose I never use this pile of exposed heating elements and wires unsafely -- will the National Safety Standards people still certify it?"  No, they won't, because it's not safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the `callvirt instance string IShow::show` instructions call the same exact stub, which jumps to a [lookup stub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/virtual-stub-dispatch.md) associated with the interface method. The lookup stub will resolve the method to be called depending on the type of the object that receives the call. In this case, the object does implement `IShow`, so everything works out fine as you can see. However, if you pass an object that does not implement `IShow`, the lookup stub will not find `IShow::show` in the object's method table and so an exception of type `EntryPointNotFoundException` is thrown.

The evaluation stack of the IL virtual machine contains an object of type `object` at the time the `callvirt` instruction is executed. The target method is `IShow::show()`. According to the CLI specification Section III.4.2, the type `object` needs to be verifier-assignable-to `IShow` in order for the IL code to be verifiable. `castclass` makes the code verifiable. In this case, since the code is fully trusted, verification is automatically skipped and so a verification exception is not thrown and method gets JIT compiled and executed.

Technically, in this case, `showWithoutCast` does not contain any IL instruction that should cause an exception of type `EntryPointNotFoundException` to be thrown as per the specification. However, since the code is not verifiable, Section II.3 of the standard states that the behavior is *unspecified* in case of a verification failure. That is, the implementation is not required to document which behavior occurs. On the other hand, the behavior of verifiable code is *specified* and `castclass` makes verification succeeds.

Note that when you build the IL code locally on your machine and run it, it will be automatically considered as fully trusted. So the JIT compiler will not verify any method.